# auto link word link in content

Tags: the-content

i use this code for auto link word in content

```
<?php function link_words($content){
$words=array(
    'test1',
    'test2',
    'test3'
);
$links=array(
    '<a href="/tag/test1/" rel="nofollow">test1</a>',
    '<a href="/tag/test2/" rel="nofollow">test2</a>',
    '<a href="/tag/test3/" rel="nofollow">test3</a>'
);
$content = str_replace($words,$links,$content);return $content;}
add_filter('the_content','link_words');
add_filter('the_excerpt','link_words'); ?>
```

but upper code have one problem, so changed and linked any word (images alt , ...)
i want only word between `<p></p>`

i want finally link any word in content to tags and categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly ... first of all you need to match everything inside paragraphs using regex.

```
$content = "<p>some text which includes test1 and test2 etc</p>";
preg_match_all("/<\s*p[^>]*>([^<]*)<\s*\/\s*p\s*>/", $content);
```

then you can use your code.